# How do I make CSS button widths be the same in MSIE and Chrome?

Tags: button, width, css

I have a problem in making the latest versions of Internet Explorer (9) look the same as Google Chrome (26.0.1).

SUMMARY
I have two buttons one is using a class called: .linkBtn
The other button is using a class called: .buynowBtn
I have tried setting them to both be 85px wide by using "min-width:85px;"
However in MSIE both buttons are 104 pixels wide... whereas in Google Chrome although the LinkBtn is 104px, the buynowBtn is 106px!

CODE
Here are the relevant CSS lines of code:

```
    .lot .lotDesc .linkBtn, .lot .lotDesc .linkBtnFinal{ /* (TJ-NEW) new style ".lot .lotDesc .linkBtnFinal" added for finalise button */
    position:absolute;
    left:8px;
    bottom:0;
    }
    .linkBtn,.linkBtnFinal{ /* (TJ-NEW) new style ".linkBtnFinal" added for finalise button */
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /* (TJ-NEW) required to standardise button widths */
    float:left;/* (TJ-NEW) required to standardise button widths */
    }
    .linkBtn a{
    min-width:85px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    }
    .buynowBtn{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /* (TJ-NEW) required to standardise button widths */
    float:left; /* (TJ-NEW-180313) */
    }
    .buynowBtn a{
    /* CSS3 Corner Radius */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    /* (TJ-NEW) the following has been added to standardise button widths */
    min-width:85px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .linkBtn a{
    color:#fff!important;
    font-size:12px!important;
    padding:0.1em 1em; /* (TJ-NEW) ? padding adjustment previously entered had been rolled back! */
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    background:#BF2A48 ; /* Old browsers */
    /* CSS3 Gradient Background */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #BF2A48 0%, #BF2A48 49%, #9B0624 51%, #9B0624 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#BF2A48 ), color-stop(49%,#BF2A48 ), color-stop(51%,#9B0624), color-stop(100%,#9B0624)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BF2A48 0%,#BF2A48 49%,#9B0624 51%,#9B0624 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #BF2A48 0%,#BF2A48 49%,#9B0624 51%,#9B0624 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #BF2A48 0%,#BF2A48 49%,#9B0624 51%,#9B0624 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #BF2A48 0%,#BF2A48 49%,#9B0624 51%,#9B0624 100%); /* W3C */
    /*filterrogidXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#BF2A48 ', endColorstr='#9B0624',GradientType=0 ); *//*IE6-8 */ /* (TJ-NEW) commented out IE style, as not working anyway and causes issue with fixed width */
    /* CSS3 Corner Radius */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    /* (TJ-NEW) the following has been added to standardise button widths */
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .linkBtn a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #9B0624;
    }



    .buynowBtn a{
    color:#fff!important;
    font-size:12px!important;
    padding:0.1em 1em; /* ******* Updated to match place bid (TJ) ******* */
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    background:#888; /* Old browsers */
    /* CSS3 Gradient Background */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #888 0%, #888 49%, #666 51%, #666 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#888), color-stop(49%,#888), color-stop(51%,#666), color-stop(100%,#666)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #888 0%,#888 49%,#666 51%,#666 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #888 0%,#888 49%,#666 51%,#666 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #888 0%,#888 49%,#666 51%,#666 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #888 0%,#888 49%,#666 51%,#666 100%); /* W3C */
    /* filterrogidXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#888', endColorstr='#666',GradientType=0 ); *//* IE6-8 */ /* (TJ-NEW) commented out IE style, as not working anyway and causes issue with fixed width */
    }
    .buynowBtn a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #444;
    }
    .buynowBtn{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /* (TJ-NEW) required to standardise button widths */
    float:left; /* (TJ-NEW-180313) */
    }
    .buynowBtn a{
    /* CSS3 Corner Radius */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    /* (TJ-NEW) the following has been added to standardise button widths */
    min-width:85px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Any thoughts?
- I tried using "width:" rather than "min-width", but the text seems to wrap onto two lines which is a disaster.

With thanks

J

Comment: Can you add the relevant html - just the specific bit regarding the buttons...

Comment: If you set it up in js fiddle we can all play with your CSS/HTML ... something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CWt4c/2/

Comment: The actual width of an element is `[width of content box (width)] + [left/right paddings] + [left/right border-widths]`:  http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of reasons why this could be happening, from differences in the box model, to differences in the font that's being used.

You can still do IE-only CSS like this:

```
<!--[if IE 9]--><link to your CSS /><!--[endif]-->
```

There are a couple of options there which let you target specific versions of IE (for example)

```
<!--[if IE]-->targets all versions of IE<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]-->targets IE 9 only<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]-->targets versions 7 and below of IE (lt: <)<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]-->targets versions 8 and up of IE (gte: >=)<!--[endif]-->
```

If the buttons absolutely have to be pixel-perfect, though, try using an image instead.

Comment: I'd only target different versions of IE as a last resort - do you really want to maintain that many browser specific stylesheets? I'd try stripping out all the CSS for the buttons in question and gradually build it back up until you see what's causing the differences. That way it'll be much more maintainable going forward (and you'll learn what it takes to make it cross-browser compatible). Also give you a chance to refactor your CSS - you've got multiple references to ".buynowBtn a" for example.